# Custom ordering in TreeMap

Tags: scala, ordereddictionary

Here are examples that I have been playing with:

```
  import collection.immutable.{TreeSet, TreeMap}
  val ts = TreeSet(9, 23, 1, 2)
  ts
  val tm = TreeMap(3 -> "c", 1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
  tm
  // convert a map to a sorted map
  val m = Map("98" -> List(4, 12, 14), "001" -> List(22, 11))
  val t = TreeMap(m.toSeq: _*)
  t // sorted by key
  // sort an unsorted map
  m.toSeq.sortWith((x, y) => x._2(0) < y._2(0))

  // add a unsorted map into a sorted map
  val m1 = Map("07" -> List(3, 5, 1), "05" -> List(12, 5, 3))
  val t1: TreeMap[String, List[Int]] = t ++ m1
  t1 // "001" is the first key
```

I can use `sortWith` on a `Map` to get a custom ordering, what if I want to use a TreeMap that uses a different ordering than the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Map`'s values to define default ordering of a Map.

`TreeMap[A,B]`'s constructor accepts an implicit `Ordering[A]` parameter, so you could do something like this:

```
// Will sort according to default Int ordering (ascending by numeric value)
scala> val tm = TreeMap(3 -> "c", 1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
tm: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c)

// A wild implicit appears! (orders descending by numeric value)
scala> implicit val tmOrd = Ordering[Int].on((x:Int) => -x)
tmOrd: scala.math.Ordering[Int] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$5@1d8e2eea

// Our implicit is implicitly (yeah) used by constructor
scala> val invTm = TreeMap(3 -> "c", 1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
invTm: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,String] = Map(3 -> c, 2 -> b, 1 -> a)
```

*Note that it's safer to limit a scope of implicits like this one. If you can, you should construct an (not-implicit) object and pass it manually, or separate the scope of implicit declaration from the place where other code can be affected by its presence.*

The reason behind this is that TreeMap is built on top of a tree that uses keys' values to maintain structure constraints that allow for efficient data reads/writes based on keys, which is the primary purpose of a Map. Ordering on values in a Map simply makes no sense.

Upd.: The complexity of ordering logic doesn't mean anything. According to your comment:

```
scala> object ComplexOrdering extends Ordering[Int] {
     |   def compare(a: Int, b: Int) = {
     |     if(a == 3) -1 else if(a == 2 * b) -1 else if(a == 3 * b) 0 else 1
     |   }
     | }
defined object ComplexOrdering

scala> val tm = TreeMap(3 -> "c", 1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
tm: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c)

scala> val tm = TreeMap(3 -> "c", 1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")(ComplexOrdering)
tm: scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Int,String] = Map(3 -> c, 2 -> b, 1 -> a)
```

Comment: What if I want to sort with a more complex function? For instance, `(x: Int, y: Int) => { if(x == 3) -1 else if(x == 2 * y) -1 else if(x == 3 * y) 0 else 1 }`.

Comment: As long as you compare keys, it doesn't matter how complex is your ordering. I'll update the answer to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

`TreeMap` is defined as a Map-like type with a specified ordering of its *keys*. That ordering is given by an implicit parameter to the constructor:

```
new TreeMap()(implicit ordering: Ordering[A]) // For TreeMap[A,B]
```

so you can set an alternative ordering on the *keys* at construction by explicitly providing a custom `Ordering[A]`.

The class does not, however, provide any (direct) means of setting an ordering based on the *values*. What you have with calling `.toSeq.sortWith` is about the best you can do as far as I know, short of coding your own collection type.